# Working on multiple projects at once in github

Tags: git

I have a multi-module maven project where the building of a parent project lasts about 3+ hours.
Let's say I do required changes in say `local_copy1` and commit locally using git commit then trigger the build. Now in another terminal, If I checkout `local_copy2` and start working will `local_copy1` be affected?

Comment: If you check out a remote repository twice, then the two *local* repositories would be independent. You have to move changes between them manually or commit + push from one and then fetch + rebase/pull from the other.

Comment: Do you mean two separate copies of the repositories, or two branches in one repository?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I mean 2 branches of same repository

Comment: @VLAZ right, after I commit my changes in one of the branches that is fine but problem is how can I work in parallel; let us say local_copy1 is in phase of building code and I want to make changes in local_copy2 during that time

Comment: The same applies. The two repositories are independent. Unless your build system only does changed in a shared location, then the two wouldn't be affected. It's literally the same as simply having two folders with the source code. If you are buildinh one and work on the other would anything be affected? If not, then Git doesn't change anything here. If your build system and/or IDE (when building things for you) shows any strange behaviour then it's not because of Git.